# Play Audio from sdcard Android Mediaplayer

Tags: android, audio, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I'm making an app that comes with three fairly large audio files build into it, and I want to play them the correct way. As I understand it, the BEST way would be to somehow have them on the Sdcard and play them there, but the only examples for how to do this are songs that were already on the device, aka the music library for example.

This code works from res/raw (raw is a folder I created, per the basic Android instructions) but this only works when I use two small sample audio files, instead of the three larger audio files I want to use which cause an "Insufficient Memory" warning (on the emulator at least)

```
MediaPlayer mp;

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void  playSong() {
        // Play song
        if(mp == null) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.rz);
        }
        mp.start();
    }
```

I tried set data source to a folder I named sdcard, but that didn't work.

Suggestions, sample code, thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to have media files inside an app is on /assets folder of the project.

But there as well you have some limit of file size, that depends on the Android implementation but should be around 1MB, at least for me this worked.

So my advice would be to divide the media files in few block files with 1MB each and get them on the assets folder.

Then when you start the app you check if the media files are at the sdcard, can be on your app's external data directory, and if not you copy them there recreating the original media files from the block files.

And that should solve your problem.

**EDIT:**

I was going into this in more detail and found out that the limit of 1MB (in assets or res/raw) is only for files that the Android packager needs to compress. If the Android packager finds that the file is already compressed, like mp3 or png, it will not compress and than there is no limit.

But also be aware that having big apk files will limit also the devices that can install it, due to limited capacities of many devices.

For big files, when possible, the best is to get them from a web server at first run.

Comment: Pedro thanks for the input! No song is smaller than 5mb, so there's no way that's the proper way to local audio files, unless there's not a single local implementation targeted at music files and they're all targeted at sound effects.